# Speeding up an Insert TSQL procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need some tip on tuning some TSQL to execute faster, it's taking way too long although it works. This may be because I'm fetching a key from another table before I can do the insert, any ideas anyone?

```
DECLARE db_cursorReads CURSOR FOR SELECT 
        [MeterId]
      ,[MeterRead]
        FROM MdsReadsImports;

declare @PremiseMeterId int;
declare @MeterId nvarchar(24);
declare @MeterRead int; 

OPEN db_cursorReads;
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursorReads INTO 
      @MeterId
      ,@MeterRead;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

    set @PremiseMeterId = (select top 1 PremiseMeterId from PremiseMeters where MeterId = @MeterId)

    insert into PremiseMeterReads (MeterRead,PremiseMeterId)
    values (@MeterRead, @MPremiseMeterId)

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursorReads INTO 
     @MeterId
      ,@MeterRead;

END;
CLOSE db_cursorReads;
DEALLOCATE db_cursorReads;
```

Comment: How big are the tables ? 
Do they have indexes ?

Comment: and as i see you don't need to use a cursor in this case, avoid them when possible

Comment: Are you sure the code is correct?  You are not using `@PremiseMeterID`.

Comment: I changed the variables there are a lot more, i'll edit in a moment and correct the mistake sorry. Tables all have around 400,000 in them, not much in the way of indexes, 1 or 2 max per table

Comment: Sorry I corrected the error in the question TSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are retrieving PremiseMeterId but not using it in the script you posted.  Perhaps you can ditch the cursor and perform a single set-based query:

```
INSERT INTO PremiseMeterReads (MeterRead,MeterId)
SELECT 
     [MeterRead]
    ,[MeterId]
FROM MdsReadsImports;
```

Comment: insert into PremiseMeterReads (Reading,PremiseMeterId,MeterReadType)
     select i.MeterRead
     ,(select top 1 PremiseMeterId from PremiseMeters where D3001_MeterId = i.D3001_MeterId)
     ,i.MeterReadType from MdsReadsImports i;

Answer (score 1):

First, I note that you are setting but not using `@PremiseMeterID`.

Second, you seem to be doing this:

```
insert into PremiseMeterReads (MeterRead, MeterId)
    select MeterRead, MeterId
    from MdsReadsImports;
```

A set based operation should be much faster than using a cursor.

Comment: This is the right approach but Check the order of parameters Gordon.